# Binary optimization on a direct-acyclic-graph(DAG)

Tags: optimization, combinatorial-geometry, topological-graph-theory

Given a DAG $G$, each edge of the DAG $e \in E(G)$ relates to a attribute $w_e \in \{-1, 1\}$

Try to find the optimized attribute setting $[w_e]$ s.t. the cost function

$$
\sum_{e\in E(G)} w_e
$$

is maximized, in another word, set as more 1 as possible. The constraints come from the DAG structure. For each path $e_s,e_i,e_j,...,e_t$ from the source node $s$ to the sink node $t$, the production of all edge attributes:

$$
w_{es} \cdot w_{ei} \cdot w_{ej} ... \cdot w_{et}
$$

must stay the same value.

In summary, the model is:

For a DAG $G$ with edges sets:

$$
Maximize \sum_{e\in E(G)} w_e\\
s.t.\; w_e\in\{-1,1\}\\
w_{es} \cdot w_{ei}  ... \cdot w_{et} = 1,\;e_s,e_i,...,e_t\;\text{is a path}\\
w_{es} \cdot w_{ej}  ... \cdot w_{et} = -1,\;e_s,e_j,...,e_t\;\text{is a path}\\
w_{es} \cdot w_{ek}  ... \cdot w_{et} = 1,\;e_s,e_k,...,e_t\;\text{is a path}\\
w_{es} \cdot w_{el}  ... \cdot w_{et} = -1,\;e_s,e_l,...,e_t\;\text{is a path}\\
...
$$

For an example, consider a DAG looks like:

```
     --> A --
s - |        | -> t
     --> B --
```

This DAG has 4 edges
$$
e_1 : s \rightarrow A\\
e_2 : s \rightarrow B\\
e_3 : A \rightarrow t\\
e_4 : B \rightarrow t\\
$$
there are two paths from s to t, let's say they have constraints like:
$$
e_1\cdot e_3 = 1\\
e_2\cdot e_4 = -1
$$

then, we need find a config $[e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4] \in \{1,-1\}^4$ that has maximum summation. Here the answer is $[1, 1, -1, 1]$

Comment: You have clearly described your problem and it seems like an interesting problem. As it is written, you are asking us to do this for you. What are your ideas about how this problem should be solved?

Comment: if we treat those productions in constraints as summation, this problem is very similar to linear programming. At least the dimension of the solution space can be analyzed in a similar way as linear programming. But I am not sure how to exactly resolve this issue in a scalable way.

Comment: I don't understand the problem statement.  You want an algorithm to solve this problem.  What are the inputs?  Are you given a list of paths, and a desired product-of-weights for each path?  A DAG can have exponentially many paths, so if you try to list that for all paths, the input to the algorithm will have exponential search, so even reading in all of them will be infeasible.  Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we set $w_e = (-1)^{x_e}$.  Then the product of weights along a path is the sum, modulo 2, of the $x$'s along that path, so each constraint is a linear equation over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  Your goal is to minimize the Hamming weight of $x$, subject to these linear equations.

So, your problem is equivalent to
$$\min_x \text{wt}(x) \quad \text{such that } Mx=0,$$
where $x \in (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$, $M$ is some $m \times n$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ representing the $m$ linear equations associated with the $m$ paths, and $\text{wt}(x)$ denotes the Hamming weight of $x$.

I believe this is closely related to the problem of finding a minimum-weight codeword in a linear code (if we think of $M$ as a parity-check matrix for a linear code).  That problem is NP-hard, but there exist subexponential time algorithms for it.  You could try applying one of them to this problem.  See, e.g., https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/119999/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/52534/755.

However, this doesn't make use of the structure afforded by the DAG.  Perhaps there are better algorithms that make use of the DAG structure.